# Create hyperlink on table result and fill editable form in other page

Tags: php, select, textbox

I'm having problems to find how to create an hyperlink in a table column result and then, on click, open another page with all fields (textboxes) filled. Imagine when a click an ID, i do a select * from table where column_id = ID... Is there a way to do it?
Thanks.

Best regards

Comment: you have to echo the result with hyperlinks

Comment: I've made an echo and it shows www.mywebsite/myphp.php&id=21093812

Comment: But now, my second page won't open...

Comment: no with the <a tag and in the href append your link

Comment: didn't understand it...

Comment: like echo '<a href='{$your_url}'> and so on

Comment: Yes, that worked... but on second page, what do i have to create/insert to get that id to work on a mysql SELECT?

Comment: which id ? paste your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking, but this may help you a bit.

First make a Javascript.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function selectID() {
var ID = document.getElementById("ID").value;
document.location.href ="yoursite.php?ID="+ID;
}
</script>
```

Then connect to your database to query the table for a link ID (or more) for example by changing the variable $value.

```
<?php  
//Connect to database
mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("db_name");

$value = 'something';
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
if (!$ID) {
$ID = 0;
}

if ($ID == 0) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `column_1` = '$value'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table>";
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a href=\"yoursite.php?ID=" . $myrow[column_id] . "\" onclick=\"selectID();\">ID</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}

elseif ($ID > 0) {
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `column_id` = '$ID'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
while($myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
$value1 = $myrow2['column_1'];
$value2 = $myrow2['column_2'];
}

echo "<form type=\"GET\" action=\"$PHP_SELF\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"ID\" name=\"ID\" value=\"$ID\"><br>";
echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"value1\" name=\"value1\" value=\"$value1\"><br>";
echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"value2\" name=\"value2\" value=\"$value2\"><br>";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"search\" name=\"search\" value=\"searching\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"submitbutton\" name=\"submitbutton\" value=\" Search \">";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
```